# VBScript class property is empty after setting a value

Tags: class, asp-classic, vbscript

I made a class in VBScript and used it in asp classic to instatiate an object:
This is my class:

```
    <%
Class RBAC

    Public dateTimeValue
    Public userIdValue
    Public fileIdValue
    Public actionValue

    Public Property Get DateTime()
            'Gets the propery value
            DateTime = dateTimeValue
        End Property    
    Public Property Set DateTime(value)
            'Sets the property value
            dateTimeValue = value
    End Property

    Public Property Get UserId()
            'Gets the propery value
            UserId = userIdValue
        End Property
    Public Property Set UserId(value)
            'Sets the property value
            userIdValue = value
    End Property

    Public Property Get FileId()
            'Gets the propery value
            FileId = fileIdValue
        End Property
    Public Property Set FileId(value)
            'Sets the property value
            fileIdValue = value
    End Property

    Public Property Get Action()
            'Gets the propery value
            Action = actionValue
        End Property
    Public Property Set Action(value)
            'Sets the property value
            actionValue = value
    End Property

    Public Sub Insert()
        sqlMethods = "INSERT INTO RBAC ([DateTime],[UserId],[FileId],[Action]) VALUES ("+dateTimeValue+","+userIdValue+","+fileIdValue+","+actionValue+",)"
        Conn.Execute(sqlMethods)
    End Sub

End Class
 %>
```

And here I instantiate an object and set it's properties:

```
    Dim RbacObject
Set RbacObject = New RBAC
Set RbacObject.DateTime = Now
Set RbacObject.UserId = Cstr(Session("cgsid"))
sqlFileId = "SELECT int_fileid FROM tbl_SecFiles where str_filename = '"&split(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"),"/cgs/")(1)&"'"
Set RS = Conn.Execute(sqlFileId)
Set RbacObject.FileId = RS("int_fileid")
Set RbacObject.Action = "<"&stringMethods&"><old>"&enabled_profiles_old&"</old><new>"&enabled_profiles_old&siteid&",</new></"&stringMethods&">"

RbacObject.Insert
```

The problem is that only **FileId** gets a value rest of the fields are empty, even if I set them an value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your SQL in the `Insert()` is wrong too. You have to wrap non numeric fields with single quote and you have extra comma in the end of the string. All in all, many syntax errors.

Comment: +1 to question because of all the great answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Set` is used for assigning **objects** to variables. So

```
Set RbacObject = New RBAC
```

is correct, but all other statements like

```
Set RbacObject.DateTime = Now
```

are not. Use

```
RbacObject.DateTime = Now
```

instead.

```
Set RbacObject.FileId = RS("int_fileid")
```

is a borderline case: `fileIdValue` will contain a Field **object**, but evaluate to its .Value when used in a 'non-object context' (like IO or computations).

You shouldn't run dubious code with/under `On Error Resume Next`.

**Demo**:

```
copy con 10.vbs
Class C
 Public V
End Class
Set O = New C
Set O.V = "don't do this at home."
^Z

cscript 10.vbs
... 10.vbs(5, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'O.V'
```

**Demo II** (to prove that 'it works' if you don't use `Set` for assignment of non-objects, and indicate that there must be other error hidden by the evil OERN if it 'still doesn't work'):

```
Class C
 Public V
End Class
Set O = New C
On Error Resume Next
Set O.V = "don't do this at home."
WScript.Echo Err.Description
On Error GoTo 0
WScript.Echo "Set O.V => '" & O.V & "'"
O.V = "don't do this at home."
WScript.Echo "O.V => '" & O.V & "'"
```

output:

```
cscript 10.vbs
Object required
Set O.V => ''
O.V => 'don't do this at home.'
```

Comment: I tried to use the RbacObject.DateTime = Now and stile empty.

Comment: I don't know why you're not a mod for the Classic ASP tag yet. +1 to your question to get you to 10k already.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what [Ekkehard.Horner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16558795/1630171) said you need to define the setters for properties that don't take objects as

```
Public Property Let name(value)
```

not as

```
Public Property Set name(value)
```